# Undefined type Intervention\Image\Facades\Image after install package spatie permission

Tags: php, laravel, image, intervention, laravel-permission

I am working on Laravel project using the following libraries:

- Spatie/Laravel-Permissions
- intervention/image

Undefined type Intervention\Image\Facades\Image

**In config/app.php I add this code:**

```
return [
......
$provides => [
    ......
    ......,
    'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
],
$aliases => [
    .....
    .....,
    'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
] ]
```

my providers

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'

],
```

my aliases

```
'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
    'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Http' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

    'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'

],
```

I use this code on the top of Controller

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image As Image;
```

This code:

```
$thumbnailImage = Image::make($originalImage);
```

Image Undefined type

I try to fresh install project laravel and Install package `composer require intervention/image` , It working fine. 
but if I install `composer require spatie/laravel-permission` at the first and Install intervention/image at the second, i will show error Undefined type Intervention\Image\Facades\Image

How to solve this issue? pls help

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `::class` like other providers and aliases, so change your aliases:

```
'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
```

to:

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

and providers from `'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'` to `Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class`

reference:
http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel